# Setting raised = true to an ember button when on current page/template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

```
   <div class="flex">
      <div class="layout-row layout-align-end-center">
        {{#paper-button href="overview" raised=true primary=true}}Overview{{/paper-button}}
        {{#paper-button href="incomes"}}Incomes{{/paper-button}}
        {{#paper-button href="expenses"}}Expenses{{/paper-button}}
        {{#paper-button href="settings"}}Settings{{/paper-button}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

So I am trying to set the **raised=true** whenever I am on certain page/template. The above code is from my **application template**. Is there any way of doing this using JS/Ember or should I just do it manually in each of my templates?

Comment: I'm not sure if `ember-paper` is a good choice here, because `{{#link-to}}` does give you some more magic you probably want. I'm actually surprised that passing a route as `href` works. You could write your own component that wraps `paper-button` tho...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to go is to write a custom component wrapping `paper-button`. [`ember-route-helpers`](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-router-helpers) gives you nice helpers to do that:

```
{{#paper-button
  onclick={{transition-to @route)
  href=(url-for @route)
  raised=(is-active @route)
  primary=(is-active @route)
}}
  {{yield}}
{{/paper-button}}
```

Then you can use that component with `{{#your-component route="settings"}}Settings{{/your-component}}`.

It's important to understand that you should pass both the action *and* the `href`. Because then when people click on the button it will make a transition and dont reload the entire page, but rightlick->open and screenreaders are are not broken.